# how to create a bean in dynamic times with different parameters

Tags: java, spring

if I have a class like this:

```
@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class TraderStarter {
private String address;
}
```

and TraderStarter should be created X times, X is dynamically determined by databases. How should I get these beans?
Only like this？

```
@Component("SpringContextUtil")
public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private  static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        SpringContextUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getBean(String name) {
        return (T) applicationContext.getBean(name);
    }
}
```

using SpringContextUtil .getBean() and set parameters for every prototype TraderStarter?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please clarify what is "X is dynamically determined by databases" ? Does the amount of these beans change in runtime or you have a configuration of X databases and want to create X beans based on these configurations known at the time of the application startup?

Comment: yes. example like this: I have a strategy table which may change record numbers, and I want to create a new bean for each record in the strategy table and each bean's parameters will be determined by record data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, prototype means that the new bean is created upon each request for this bean (injections into different classes / getBean call).

So if you want to create these prototype beans, someone triggers this process.

Of course one way is to use the `ApplicationContext` but IMO its a bad approach, since your code becomes coupled to spring.

You cannot inject prototype into the singleton, this doesn't work.
However you can use `javax.inject.Provider` interface that is integrated with Spring:

Here is an example:

```
// from your example
// you can use injection here and everything, its a regular spring bean
@Service 
@Scope("prototype")
public class TraderStarter {
  private String address;

  public void setAddress(String address) {
      this.address = address;
  }   
}   

///////////////////////
@Component 
public class MyDbManager {

    private Provider<TraderStarter> traderStarterProvider; 

    public List<TraderStarter> dynamicallyCreateBeans() {
           List<String> addresses = dbManager.findAllAddresses();// to to the db, get the data
           return 
                addresses.stream()
                .map(this::createTraderStarter)  // <-- creates different beans! 

                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private TraderStarter createTraderStarter(String address) {
        TraderStarter ts = provider.get();
        ts.setAddress(address);
        return ts;
    }    
}
```

There are other methods as well with factories (see ObjectFactory) and creating proxies (Lookup method and scoped proxy), but IMO this is the most clean approach.

In any case if you opt for other solutions, read [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton)